# Updating a JLabel when a JTextField get written, which event should I use?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, documentlistener

I want a label to show the same as the text field has. Using KeyTyped falls behind one key stroke every time, while using  KeyPressed does quite similar.

ActionPerformed does nothing until I hit enter.

```
private void myTextFieldKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        cicloLabel.setText(myTextField.getText()+" horas apagado.");
    }
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) here and call `setText` on your label.